# bat file: loop through files and manipulate with results

Tags: variables, for-loop, batch-file, copy

problem intro:
Dead Island game crashes once save file exceeds certain file size. Files are archives, but with .sav extension rather than .zip.
I want to make a script that will loop through *.sav files, copy them to another location with same file name, but as *.zip, then extract them, check extracted file size, and alert me if file size exceeds the limit.

So far, I got this:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%i IN ("D:\Games\Dead Island\out\save\"*.sav) DO (
set str=
set str=!str!%%i
set str=!str:.sav=.zip!
echo !str!
copy %%i !str!
)
PAUSE
```

for some reason bat files have problems assigning values to variables within FOR loops, so I found a solution to use delayedexpansion.

**but currently my biggest problem is that it just wont copy save_1.sav to another location with name save_1.zip!**

once I get past this, I will dive into 7zip unpacking and file size verification (along with all other stuff needed), but this is just frustrating :)
maybe I should just do this in python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the file extension of something, you can use `%%~n<variable>` to get the stem, like so (taken from one of my batch files):

```
FOR %%f IN (*.ebr) DO (
    hcsg -c %%f %%~nf.cg1
    hbsp -c %%~nf.cg1 nohints %%~nf.ct1
    hportal -c %%~nf.ct1 %%~nf.cp
    hflood -c %%~nf.ct1 %%~nf.cp %%~nf.cg2
    hbsp -c %%~nf.cg2 nohints %%~nf.ct2
)
```

This might be useful:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true

In your case, I guess you could just do something like:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.sav) DO (
    copy %%f %%~nf.zip
)
```

(Just tested this at the command line -- where you use % instead of %% if you want to try it -- and it works.)

Comment: worked like a charm once I enclosed both paths in quotemarks.thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems nobody has thought of this gem, but here is how to utilise a %variable% inside a FOR loop instead of %%variable so you can manipliate it.

put this inside of D:\superrename.bat:

```
@echo off
set CURRFILE=%1
set CURRFILE=%CURRFILE:~6%
set CURRFILE=FREN%CURRFILE%
if "%1" == "" (
for %%F in (*) do call d:\superrename.bat %%F
) else (
echo we found %1 which will become %CURRFILE%
)
```

What this does is allow you to use normal variable manipulations inside a FOR command (WITHOUT delayed expansion). i intend on removing the first few characters of the file names (in this case six characters) with rename. must have set on the outside of if otherwise if before echo, echo's output will lag by one execution of FOR.

"we found xntimer.ini which will become FRENr.ini"

limitations:
please note that if %%F contains a space then multiple parameters get passed to the batch file (%2, %3 and so on get used). If quotes are tried then CALL will not work right, saying [second word] not expected at this time.

The way around this is to specify %* instead of %1 in both places above.

Second limitation: With FOR command. it will see some of the renamed files and do them again!!! best to use copy to another dir or the like. (problem could be related to bug in https://superuser.com/questions/475874 ... in my case i had about 8 random items to fix of over 100 files.)

happy coding!

Comment: replace the `call d:\superrename.bat %%F` with `start /low "cmd /c "call superrename.bat "%%F"""` and you'll have yourself a parallel (multi-process) loop :)